# How would I construct a regex expression that validates a percentage?

Tags: regex

I am quite new when it comes to regex and I am having a bit of trouble when it comes to what I want to do.

Essentially I want to create a pattern that only accepts inputs of the following kind

- A number from 0 - 100 (not including decimals)
- Or a number from 0 - 100 (not including decimals) followed by a percentage sign

So some sample inputs would be

```
65 - Valid
65% - Valid
-1 - Not Valid
101% - Not valid
65.5 - Not valid
65.5% - Not valid
65 % - Not valid
%65 - Not valid
```

Anything else shouldn't be valid

Currently I've come up with `/[0-9](?:\%)?/` but this won't cover all the valid cases.

What do I need to change in my pattern to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: `^(?:[1-9]?\d|100)%?$`

Comment: `0` and `0%`  are both valid, right?